# How can I overload RStudio's View function for custom data frames?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using RStudio and wish to define a View method for a specially classed data.frame, but still keep the existing View method for a standard data.frame/matrix object.

The RStudio default:

- data.frame or matrix objects open in a tabular browser, in the Source pane, when using `View(x)` or when clicking on the object in the Environment pane.

When I try to redefine the methods using this code, I get the behaviour indicated below.  My specially classed object views the way I want, but standard data.frame objects no longer invoke the spreadsheet-type browser in the Source pane.

How can I add new `View()` behaviour for my object, but keep the original behaviour as well?

```
iris_myclass <- iris
class(iris_myclass) <- c("myclass", "data.frame")

View(iris)
## opens a tabular data browser in the Source pane
View(iris_myclass)
## opens a tabular data browser in the Source pane

View <- function(x, title) {
    UseMethod("View")
}

View.default <- function(x, title) {
    utils::View(x, title)
}

View.myclass <- function(x, title) {
    DT::datatable(x)
}

View(iris)
## opens an Xwindows Viewer
View(iris_myclass)
## opens an HTML datatable browser in the Viewer pane
```

My settings: RStudio Version 1.0.136 and

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DT_0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

It does work like this:

```
View.default <- function(...) {
  get('View', as.environment('package:utils'))(...)
}
```

`utils::View` and `mget('View')` return different functions. As @KevinUshey explains, Rstudio overrides `View` on the search path (within the `package:utils` environment), but not in the `utils` namespace. So we can't access it with `utils::View`, but we *can* with `mget`.

Using `get` instead of `mget` is even a bit nicer (thanks @Willem).

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is there any way to do this *without* redefining the generic? So that when my package is attached, I do not get NAMESPACE conflict warnings with `utils::View`, after redefining object as a generic?

Comment: Note that the original `View` is not a generic, there is no dispatch, it just coerces everything to a data.frame. Not sure what to do about the name conflict.

Comment: Quite right, I should have said: "without redefining `View` as a generic". (`sample` is the other function I have to redefine as a generic in my package, which creates one more conflict note to users that they find scary but has no effect, since the `.default` methods calls the preexisting non-generic.)

Comment: If you are worried about scaring users, you could consider printing an additional startup message to explain. Otherwise you'll have to rename your functions.

Comment: RStudio overrides `View` in the environment on the search path (`package:utils`), but not in the actual `utils` namespace. Compare the output of `View` and `utils::View` in the console.

Comment: I would like to suggest updating this to:
`View.default <- function(...) {
  get('View', as.environment('package:utils'))(...)
}`. Reasons: 1) `mget` is to get multiple objects, `get` is an easier version if you only need one object which is the case here. 2) This way the tab in Rstudio correctly displays the name of the table you are viewing, instead of the default "X".

Comment: Note that changing the arguments to `...` is also an improvement: when working in Rstudio the name of the tab displaying the data will be named correctly instead of just "x".

Comment: @Willem, sorry was too quick the last time around. Fixed now.